# unable to highlight menu on pagereload and button click

Tags: jquery

i am trying to highlight current page in menu... it works fine with the page load but not with page reload...

here is the code i am using in jquery..

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var url = window.location;
    $('ul.nav a[href="' + url + '"]').parent().parent().parent().parent().addClass('active');
    $('li').removeClass('active');
    $('ul.nav a').filter(function () {
        return this.href == url;
        $('li.a').siblings().removeClass("active");
    }).parent().addClass('active').parent().parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

});
```

this is not working on button click as well. please help me... thank you.....

Comment: Can you please create a JSFiddle example.

Comment: @Stormblessed I am sorry to say that i con't...........  my menu items will be listed dynamically......

Comment: It doesn't matter. Create a mock menu so we can see the html, css and javascript code. It'll help us help you.

Comment: Well to debug, you should maybe `console.log(window.location)`, so you can see if there is a difference when loading the page and reloading the page. It could be that the page is reloading from the cache giving a different `window.location` back. See if `reload.location(true)` is giving back the correct url. `true` forces your browser to get the page from the server not from te chache